# Return JSON response in Laravel for duplicate email login via API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

This is my API register method for taking new user registration into the Database.

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
       $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
        if($user->save()){
           response (['result' => true]);
        }
        return response(['result' => false,]);
    }
```

Now when I register from the same email Id, I am getting errors like below

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'pkyadav@gmail.com' for key 'users_email_unique' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Pramod, pkyadav@gmail.com, y$WJJrNjB8K/jGSXpPagVjSujZcifKXrzs3gnvPcjSK3W1c.IekaBna, 2021-12-16 07:46:56, 2021-12-16 07:46:56))
```

I want to get a false result response on a duplicate email registration

Comment: Use [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation) then

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI that's not a good idea

Comment: You can use following validation: if(!$user->where('email',$request->input('email'))->exists())

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei, you're right, I read question for second time and saw that he's seeking for a prevention. So I suggest using [unique validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Validation using Exists:
Example: `$user->where('email',$request->input('email'))->exists()`

See the below code:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
   $user = new User();
   if(!$user->where('email',$request->input('email'))->exists()){
      $user->name = $request->input('name');
      $user->email = $request->input('email');
      $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
      if($user->save()){
        return response(['result' => true]);
      }else{
        return response(['result' => false]);
      }
   }
   return response(['result' => false,]);
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what your code does and why OP should try this.

Comment: Shouldn't `response()`s be `return`ed?

Comment: I am always getting false results. even trying to register with the new email.

Comment: Use Try catch for "$user->save()", So you can get message If there are any error

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel validation:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|unique:users',
        ]);

    if($validation->fails()){
        return response()->json($validation->errors());
    }

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
        if($user->save()){
           return response (['result' => true]);
        }
        return response(['result' => false,]);
    }
```

Comment: Getting false on successfully registered otherwise not getting any response

Comment: You have forgotten to return the response in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can be use Form Request.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation

or you can use the following

```
public function register(Request $request){
    $data = $request->validate([
        'email'     => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'name'      => 'required|string',
        'password'  => 'required|string'
    ]);

    $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);

    try {
        User::create($data);
        return response()->json([
            'message' => __('User created'),
            'result'  => true
        ]);
    }catch (\Exception $exception){
        return response()->json([
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'result'  => false
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Rouf, I am getting users registered successfully but on duplicate user registration, I am getting some Html tags. like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/AojA3.png

Comment: Hi, Pramod if you use login route in web.php, you have to use csrf token {_token}.
f you want to use a token, you must also specify it in the VerifyCsrfToken file or use api.php files

Comment: Right sir. Thanks